# File not found during building GStreamer on VC6

Tags: windows, installation, gstreamer, visual-c++-6

I'm having a problem to build GStreamer on Visual C++ 6. I've tried to find the solution for this, but I couldn't..

When I was trying to build the library, I had the next problem:

```
Deleting intermediate files and output files for project 'grammar - Win32 Debug'.
Deleting intermediate files and output files for project 'libgstreamer - Win32 Debug'.
Build : warning : failed to (or don't know how to) build             'M:\MPC_Server\Programs\GSTREAMER1806\GStreamer2\gstreamer-p4\gst\parse\lex._gst_parse_yy.c'
--------------------Configuration: grammar - Win32 Debug--------------------
Performing Custom Build Step on ..\common\gstversion.h
        1 fichier(s) copi‚(s).
Performing Custom Build Step on ..\..\gst\gstmarshal.list
        1 fichier(s) d‚plac‚(s).
        1 fichier(s) d‚plac‚(s).
Performing Custom Build Step on ..\common\gstenumtypes.c
        1 fichier(s) copi‚(s).
        1 fichier(s) copi‚(s).
Performing Custom Build Step on ..\common\gstconfig.h
        1 fichier(s) copi‚(s).
Performing Custom Build Step on ..\..\gst\parse\grammar.y
Le fichier sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
Le fichier sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
Le fichier sp‚cifi‚ est introuvable.
Error executing c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe.

libgstreamer-0.10.dll - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Can anybody help me please?

I can not upgrade my VC version and I am using the Windows Server 2003.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I've decided not to build it instead..

The problem I was having is because I am using a computer with restrictions and I couldn't even execute an .exe file to get the files from GStreamer, so I was trying to generate the bins, includes and lib using the installing instructions.

So, I've just executed the file at home, in my own PC, and then I've sent the files by dropbox...

Now everything works! =) I still can't build it to have the debug files, but the release files are OK!